# Google search console DNS verification failed

Tags: dns, verification, google-search-console

I'm trying to add my website to Google Search Console, but all time it's failed. I add DNS record

- Type: TXT
- name: @
- value: google-site-verification=myVerificationString

Saved it

Waited some time and tried button verify.

I'm getting verification failed

> Failure reason:
>   We couldn't find your verification token in your domain's TXT records.
>   We found these DNS TXT records instead:

- google-site-verification=myVerificationSt
- ring

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuirS.png)

I cannot found any answer for it. Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably a problem with your DNS provider, most likely they are dividing TXT records on 64 characters strings. I had same problem and they fixed it for me so try to ask them.